fingerprint sensor supported by ubuntu 24.04
Does anybody have a suggestion for a USB fingerprint sensor that works with ubuntu 24.04?

I have used YubiKey products for years, and they do have a model with a fingerprint reader. This would be a more complete solution for access security than a simple USB biometric device

Thanks for the input. I will look again at yubikey. I had hoped for a simpler solution that just had a fingerprint sensor that would work seamlessly with the existing linux/ubuntu authentication system.

In case anybody else sees this. I have already bought a "HID DigitalPersona URU4500 USB Fingerprint Reader" based on a internet article that said it works with ubuntu. It doesn't work at this time and I cannot find a unix driver hidglobal website. I will keep looking at that solution and am interested in any other suggestions.
